# Some issue with an enhanced for loop-SimpleDotCom

Tags: java

This is a modified example from the book, Head First Java. It's a kind of Battleship game where a 3 element array is being used as the battleship. The user has to guess these 3 locations. Currently, I've hard-coded the values of the ship location to 2,3,4. When the user guesses the correct location "Hit" is printed. If not then "Miss" is printed. If a user guesses all 3 locations then "Kill" is printed.  But I have a problem. Currently if the user enters the same location multiple times, it still gives a hit. I tried to fix this by changing the value of a variable that has already been hit (int cell) to "-1". But for some reason this didn't fix it too. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int [] location = {2,3,4};
        SimpleDotCom firstGame = new SimpleDotCom();

        firstGame.setLocation(location);

        firstGame.checkYourself("2");
        firstGame.checkYourself("2");
        //firstGame.checkYourself("2");
    }

}


public class SimpleDotCom {
    int [] loc = null;
    int numOfHits = 0;

    void setLocation (int [] cellLocation){
        loc = cellLocation;
    }

    void checkYourself(String userGuess){

        int guess = Integer.parseInt(userGuess);
        String result = "Miss";

        for(int cell:loc){
                        if (guess == cell){
                            result = "Hit";
                            numOfHits++;
                            cell = -1;
                            break;
                            }
                        if (numOfHits==loc.length){
                            result = "Kill";
                            }

        }
        System.out.print("Result: " + result);
        System.out.println(" ** Num of Hits: " + numOfHits);
}

    }
```

Comment: Program is quite short and simple, have you tried to debug it?

Comment: No. I've forgotten how to debug. Googling it now.

Comment: You have to remove the element from your Array if "Hit" is printed.

Comment: I'm not removing that element I'm just changing it value to something the user won't guess (which in this case is -1). Its the same thing right?

Comment: You guys are really fast. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you loop over `loc`, you get an `int cell` for each location. The problem is that that variable doesn't have any connection to the array, it's only a copy. If you change it, nothing's going to happen to the original array. I suggest looping over `loc` with a traditional `for(;;)` and using the current array index within the loop's logic to set the right "cells" to -1.

Comment: Thanks, I did'nt know that.

Answer (score 1):

because you are assigning -1 to local variable. not updating in array actually

```
 for(int cell:loc){  // cell is local copy of element in array is you have array of primitive int
    if (guess == cell){
       result = "Hit";
       numOfHits++;
       cell = -1;
       break;
     }
     if (numOfHits==loc.length){
         result = "Kill";
      }
  }
```

You can use traditional for loop for this or use `List` which has methods for adding removing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the array at the correct index, not simply change the value of the `cell` variable, which only references the array element at the current iteration state.

You should probably use a traditionnal for loop for that, since you cannot get the index for free from an enhanced for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
   //code...

   loc[i] = -1; //instead of cell = -1; 
}
```